# How to reverse singly linked list recursively

Tags: python

Recursively reverse the order of nodes from current to the end in self.
        Split the current node and its successors (remainders).
        Recursively reverse the successors and make its tail pointing current node.
        Make current node to point None.

```
class _Node:

    def __init__(self, element, next=None):
        self._element = element
        self._next = next

    def element(self):
        return self._element

    def next(self):
        return self._next

    def set_element(self, element):
        self._element = element

    def set_next(self, next):
        self._next = next

def __init__(self, head=None):
    """Create a singly linked list that contains only head, not size"""
    self._head = head


def __str__(self):
    """Returns the string representation and the number of elements"""
    count = 0
    p = self._head
    rep = f''
    while p:
        rep += str(p.element()) + ' -> '
        p = p.next()
        count += 1
    rep += f'None: {count} element(s)'
    return rep
```

---

```
def reverse_recursively(self, current):

    if current is None:
        return current
    if current._next is None:
        return current
    successors = self.reverse_recursively(current.next())
    current._next._next = current
    current._next = None
```

I expected the output of reversing but the actual output is only the first node and none.

Comment: A few things jump out at me: (1) you're not doing anything with `successors`; (2) `current._next._next = current` looks very odd if we're not talking a circular list; (3) `current._next = None` clearly wipes out everything beyond the current element (i.e. the list head).

Comment: Ok. but I  have no idea to where to put it...

Comment: Perhaps start by working through a few examples by hand on a sheet of paper.

Comment: Could you please fix the indentation? There seems to be only one class `_Node`, but there are methods outside of it...

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is indeed not correct, because it does not redirect the `self._head` property to point to the last node.

In fact, you should not need to pass an argument to this method. Instead move `self._head` progressively as you recurse towards the end of the linked list.

Here is how the code could look:

```
def reverse_recursively(self):
    current = self._head
    if current is None:
        return
    successor = current._next
    if successor is None:
        return
    current._next = None
    self._head = successor
    self.reverse_recursively()
    successor._next = current
```